# checking if username exists in mysql through javascript with input.onkeyup

Tags: javascript, python, flask

On the register page of the site, I want to run javascript to see if username exists in the database. This would happen onkeyup. If it does match, there should be an html alert stating this. Otherwise, the user can continue with registration

I've tried the code below. I'm new to this.

```
let input = document.querySelector('username');
input.onkeyup = function() 
{
    let html = '';
    let $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = username");
    if (input.value == $result) 
    {
        alert("Username already taken");
    }
};
```

I expected something to happen. but nothing does.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, a bunch of issues I see here. Firstly, you're attempting to perform an asynchronous operation in a synchronous context.

Disclaimer: I'm not a PHP person (`mysql_query` seems to be PHP?), so  if that's what you're trying to do, I may not be your guy. If this is *not* the case - if you expect `mysql_query` to be a function - you're going to need to have that defined somewhere else.

Let's start by `console.log()`ing *every*thing:

- `console.log` your `$result` right after it's (possibly) generated. What does that say? I'm going to *guess* it's "undefined" or "null", since database queries are almost *always* going to be asynchronous.
- `console.log` your `input.value`. Is that what you think it should be? I can't tell you the number of times I've done something as stupid as misspelling "myDiv" as "my-div" or something. Since "username" is not a standard DOM element, I highly expect what you wanted to do here is something like `document.querySelector('#username')` (by id), or `document.querySelector('input[name=username]')` (by name).
- Lastly, I'm not really a DB guy, but your SQL syntax confuses me (other users: feel free to call me an idiot here!). You're passing in a string literal that looks in the `users` table `WHERE username = username`. Here's the issue, however (assuming your table does, in fact, have a 'username' column, this will I believe only look for users whose username is *literally* "username". In other words, if whatever you type into the input box is not exactly "username", this will fail. What you instead wanna do, I believe, is something like this:

```js
//firstly, let's assume mysql_query is an async JavaScript function that you've defined.
mysql_query(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ${input.value}`, function(err, response){
  if(err){
    alert('ERROR CHECKING NAMES!');
  }else if (response.length){
    //assume that if the query returns anything, that means it found a matching (==duplicate) name
    alert('NAME ALREADY EXISTS!');
  }else{
    //do nothing!
  }
});
```

I'd also be very careful, as it can often be "polite" to not trigger this event on every `keyup` trigger, but instead do something like this to "debounce the function:

```js
myTimer = null;
someThing.onkeyup = function(e){
  if(myTimer){
    //myTimer was previously defined. Cancel its sending and then
    clearInterval(myTimer)
  }
  //start a new timer
  setTimeout(function(){
    doSomeAPICall()
  },500)//or whatever milliseconds
}
```

I think you might have a slightly bigger issue here, however, as you're mixing PHP and JS syntax a bit, and calling it Python.